# dexedLibs folder in android project

Tags: android, developer-tools

So I have noticed fairly recently a folder within my Phonegap/Android project (project/bin/dexedLibs) and this folder contains two .jar files. After scratching around the internet, I found one website in which the author says ADT version 21 puts "pre-dexed Libs" in the project to enable faster build times.

I did upgrade recently to ADT 21 and was just wondering if anybody else can give me more information on what these "pre-dexed Libs" really do? I haven't been able to find any other useful info on the net.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have an Android project with about 20 external libraries. Before ADT 21, every time I changed source code it took ages to rebuild the app. Now it's quite fast!

I guess the reason is that, before ADT 21, it compiled the external libraries into dex code every time you hit the "Run" button in eclipse. Now it will compile the dex code for the external libraries only once (until they change) and use the prebuild libraries for later "Run"s.

I like that feature!

Comment: Thanks Jane - This confirms what the author meant when he said this feature helps with "faster build" times.

Answer (score 5):

Be aware! I've just spent an hour to find out why I get the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

The reason was because I changed my lib jar to new jar (the same name) with working method, and ADT 21 didn't prepare the new one in dexedLibs.

So just delete bin dir and Eclipse will recreate this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about 2 years old yet still of interest.

For people who browse here later: I just had trouble because I renamed a Cordova project from `my.name.a3e` to `my.name.A3E` and then the build process crashed. Came out that the dexed files in ant-build were not refreshed (case sensitivity). It worked fine after I deleted the `ant-build` folder, but the build took longer the first time after.

A dex file is a Dalvik EXecutable file, some compiled byte code that can be executed by the Dalvik virtual machine. Dalvik is a core component of Android, so that's why it is there.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dexer/
http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html
http://fileinfo.com/extension/dex

Note that Eclipse project clean won't remove dexed libs.